# Artifacts in edge labels in tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, graphs, edge

I have this code which I am compiling with luatex:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, positioning, quotes}
\usegdlibrary{force}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[spring layout, nodes={circle,draw}]
    {
        s[x=0, y=4] -> {d[>"3(5)"], c[>"1(1)"], a[>"2(4)"]};
        a[x=3,y=3] -> ["2(5)"]b;
        b[x=6,y=3] -> ["3(3)"]t;
        c[x=3, y=5] -> {b[>"1(1)"], t[>"0(2)"]};
        d[x=0, y=6] -> {c[>"0(2)"], e[>"3(6)"]};
        e[x=3, y=7] -> {f[>"1(2)"], t[>"2(2)"]};
        f[x=6,y=7] -> ["1(3)"]t;
        t[x=9, y=5];
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In the result I get these artifacts and I don't know why:

[image]

I would like that it looked like this instead:

[image]

Comment: The `>` accumulate. You need `clear >` before it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I entirely understand what you mean.

Comment: I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [options of `>` will accumulate](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#sec-19.6.3).

This is why the `1(1)` to `c` (from `s`) also shows up at the edge from `d` to `c`.

Specifying

```
a -> [options] b
```

is not the same as

```
a -> b[> options]
```

In the latter, all following edges *to* `b` will inherit `options`.

See this small example (there are examples in the manual but they are unnecessary complicated):

```
\tikz\graph[no placement]{
  a[x=0, y=0],
  b[x=0, y=1],
  c[x=1, y=0, > red],
  d[x=1, y=1],
  c --[dashed] a,      % not red since it leaves c
  d -- c,              % red!
  b -- c[> bend left], % still red
  a -- c,              % still red and bent
};
```

All edges to (not from) `c` will be red, and once `> bend left` is added to `c` all following edges to `c` will be bent, too.
[image]

You will need to use [`clear >`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/clear:%3E) or need to specify your graph differently.

I have reordered your graph because it wasn't easy for me to figure out what happens where.
I've also removed any reference to the Graph Drawing library (and the need for Lua) since you place the nodes manually anyway.

As an alternative, I've added almost the same diagram as a TikZ-CD (`tikz-cd` package or `cd` library).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, positioning, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\tikz\graph[no placement, nodes={circle,draw}]{
  a[x=3, y=3],
  b[x=6, y=3],
  c[x=3, y=5],
  d[x=0, y=6],
  e[x=3, y=7],
  f[x=6, y=7],
  s[x=0, y=4],
  t[x=9, y=5],
  a -> ["2(5)"]b,
  s -> {d[>"3(5)"],
        c[>"1(1)"],
        a[>"2(4)"]},
  b -> ["3(3)"]t,
  c -> {b[>"1(1)"],
        t[>"0(2)"]},
  d -> {c[clear >, >"0(2)"],
        e[>"3(6)"]},
  e -> {f[>"1(2)"],
        t[clear >, >"2(2)"]},
  f -> [clear >, "1(3)"]t,
};
\tikz\graph[no placement]{
  a[x=0, y=0],
  b[x=0, y=1],
  c[x=1, y=0, > red],
  d[x=1, y=1],
  c --[dashed] a,      % not red since it leaves c
  d -- c,              % red!
  b -- c[> bend left], % still red
  a -- c,              % still bent
};
\begin{tikzcd}[
  math mode=false,
  row sep={1cm,between origins},
  column sep={3cm,between origins},
  cells={nodes={circle, draw, text height=.7em, text depth=+0pt}},
  arrows=-Latex,
]
& e \ar[r,   "1(2)"] \ar[rrdd, "2(2)"]
& f \ar[ddr, "1(3)"]                                   \\
  d \ar[ur,  "3(6)"] \ar[dr,   "0(2)"]                 \\
& c \ar[rr,  "0(2)"] \ar[ddr,  "1(1)"]
& & t                                                  \\
  s \ar[uu,  "3(5)"] \ar[ur,   "1(1)"] \ar[dr, "2(4)"] \\
& a \rar["2(5)"]
& b \ar[ruu, "3(3)"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following TikZ code produces what you want when Typeset in LaTex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.40, transform shape]
\tikzstyle{every node} = [minimum size = 0.78cm]
\node (v1) [scale = 2.07, color = black, fill = white, circle, draw = black] at (2.77,16.05) {\textbf {$d$}};
\node (v2) [scale = 2.07, color = black, fill = white, circle, draw = black] at (10.78,18.71) {\textbf {$e$}};
\node (v3) [scale = 2.07, color = black, fill = white, circle, draw = black] at (18.81,18.71) {\textbf {$f$}};
\node (v4) [scale = 2.07, color = black, fill = white, circle, draw = black] at (26.79,13.38) {\textbf {$t$}};
\node (v5) [scale = 2.07, color = black, fill = white, circle, draw = black] at (18.83,8.08) {\textbf {$b$}};
\node (v6) [scale = 2.07, color = black, fill = white, circle, draw = black] at (10.78,13.35) {\textbf {$c$}};
\node (v7) [scale = 2.07, color = black, fill = white, circle, draw = black] at (10.80,8.08) {\textbf {$a$}};
\node (v8) [scale = 2.07, color = black, fill = white, circle, draw = black] at (2.77,10.68) {\textbf {$s$}};
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v1) -- (v2);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v2) -- (v3);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v3) -- (v4);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v2) -- (v4);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v6) -- (v4);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v5) -- (v4);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v7) -- (v5);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v6) -- (v5);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v8) -- (v6);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v8) -- (v7);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v8) -- (v1);
\draw [->,>=triangle 60, black, line width = 0.6]  (v1) -- (v6);
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (14.79,7.42) {2(5)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (5.65,8.94) {2(4)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (1.55,13.42) {3(5)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (8.01,15.50) {0(2)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (7.70,11.56) {1(1)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (15.77,11.37) {1(1)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (18.81,12.70) {0(2)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (17.61,15.61) {2(2)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (23.88,10.31) {3(3)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (23.81,16.67) {1(3)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (14.72,19.55) {1(2)};
\node[scale = 2.8, black] at  (5.70,17.95) {3(6)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Graph Created for TikZ]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! For start +1!

Answer (score 0):

With use of `positioning` and `quotes` libraries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=.40, transform shape,
node distance = 5mm and 15mm,
     N/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=7mm, inner sep=0pt,
                 node contents={$\bm{#1}$}},
every edge/.append style = {-Triangle, semithick},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, sloped}
                    ]
\node (v1)  [N=d];
\node (v2)  [N=e, above right=of v1];
\node (v3)  [N=f,       right=of v2];
\node (v4)  [N=c, below right=of v1];
\node (v5)  [N=t, right=of v4 -| v3];
\node (v6)  [N=s, below  left=of v4];
\node (v7)  [N=a, below right=of v6];
\node (v8)  [N=b,       right=of v7];

\draw   (v1) edge["3(6)"]   (v2) 
        (v2) edge["1(2)"]   (v3) 
        (v3) edge["1(3)"]   (v5)
        (v2) edge["2(2)"]   (v5)
        %
        (v1) edge["0(2)"]   (v4)
        (v4) edge["0(2)"]   (v5)
        (v4) edge["1(1)"]   (v8)
        %
        (v6) edge["3(5)"]   (v1)
        (v6) edge["1(1)"]   (v4)
        (v6) edge["2(4)"]   (v7)
        (v7) edge["2(5)"]   (v8)
        (v8) edge["3(3)"]   (v5)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]